# ClassCastException on List.sort

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I have an entity bean, we'll call MyEntity.  After getting a List, I sort them with the following:

```
List<MyEntity> results = query.getResultList();
results.sort((e1, e2)->e1.getKey().getTime().compareTo(e2.getKey().getTime()));
```

Where getTime is a Long.

However, at the sort line, I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.beanpackage.MyBean cannot be cast to com.beanpackage.MyBean
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
```

Telling me that it can't cast MyBean to MyBean doesn't make any sense.  Same version of Java that compiled the code is running the code, so it's not a class version issue (at least that I can figure).

The class sorting MyBean is a SLSB that lives in com.beanpackage.subpackage, so it's in a child package of where MyBean is.  Don't think that should matter.

This is running in Wildfly 9.

Has anyone else seen this?  Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This issue is cause when the same class is loaded by different class-loaders, hence the cryptic message "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.beanpackage.MyBean cannot be cast to com.beanpackage.MyBean"

Comment: By the way, use `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey().getTime())` to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! First, Holger I appreciate the code tip, still getting used to Java 8isms (we're an aerospace company, I'm jazzed just to be finally using Java 8 and Wildfly), so I always appreciate ways to minimize code without sacrificing readability.

And MJSG, that was exactly the issue.  I didn't realize the build process was sticking the package in two different jars (it's a legacy package that I am in the process of updating).  I excluded MyBean from the second jar that it didn't really need to be in and everything worked great.

I appreciate the help, cheers!